# Can not load design page in WP7 project

Tags: windows-phone-7

I had create a WP7 project. After I re-install Windows operator for my laptop. I open that project but it can not load design page and show a message.

[screen shot message](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-JrqWf5_NB60/T8RdAFV09PI/AAAAAAAAAVQ/NLmWR_9x_GA/s606/Capture.jpg)

I can not solver this error.
Give me some solution, please. Thank

Comment: Have you reinstalled/repaired all the tools since reinstalling the OS? What about if you start a new project?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "Click here to reload the designer" and see if the problem solves.

If not, restart the visual studio and then rebuild it.
hopefully this should solve your problem.